# fastboot connect remote device

Tags: android, adb, fastboot

I have device that connected to my PC over wifi/ethernet.
After `adb reboot bootloader` device moves to the fastboot mode.

How can I connect it back with `fastboot`/ or how can I flash image on it.
I even can't `ping` my device.

Comment: Any output for `fastboot devices`?

Comment: @shoerat No, but devices in fastboot mode... How to save connection in fastboot mode?

Comment: How did you configure your host PC's Ethernet adapter or wifi? If you can't even ping your device fastboot -t <ip_address> won't help you.

Comment: The fastboot system I know only works via USB, not via Ethernet or Wifi. Are you sure the fastboot system installed on your device supports networking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fastboot devices` Should show you your device connected to your PC when its in fastboot mode. If your device isn't shown up then you might lack the adb driver for your device. `fastboot -t` should be invalid, cause you can "only" use `-w/u/s/l/p/c/i/b/n` as a parameter for the `fastboot cmd`.

But whats even more important: `fastboot` should only work on USB connected devices, however you managed it to connect it via ethernet/wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your bootloader and make sure that your fastboot is correctly configred.

It must be able to bring up the wifi/ethernet interface and perform a DHCP or set a static ip address before you can connect to it.

If you are sure that the device could get an IP address in fastboot mode, plese try to get connected to it firstly by ping its ip address. If you got no react, try to use wireshark to capture some trace to see if there is something wrong (firewall issue?).